# Using Database link in stored procedure throwing exception ORA-02063

Tags: oracle

I have created a database link named 'MC_Link'. 
Using that link I am passing some records from Database1 to Database2.
I am inserting atleast 100 records using that MC_Link and doing commit at the end.

```
 Declare
    CURSOR c_arch
    IS
    SELECT EmpId FROM Employee WHERE update_dts < (SYSDATE-365) AND ROWNUM <= 100;
    Begin
    FOR i IN c_arch
        LOOP
    Insert into table1 (colum1,colum2) select colum1,colum2 from table1@MC_Link where EmpId=i.EMPId ;
    Insert into table2 (colum1,colum2) select colum1,colum2 from table2@MC_Link EmpId=i.EMPId ;
    Insert into table3 (colum1,colum2) select colum1,colum2 from table3@MC_Link
    EmpId=i.EMPId ;
    End LOOP;
    Commit;
    End;
```

I need to do it as batch wise so i have given the rownum as above and have use only one commit.

First it was running fine but now I am getting the error 'ORA-02049: timeout: distributed transaction waiting for lock'

Can anyone help me on this error?? What I am missing here?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have uncommitted changes in another session; possibly directly on the remote database, or from an earlier run of this if you lost your connect (for example)? Not really related, but why do you need to do it in batches, and why in PL/SQ - rather than three simple inserts that each join your local table to one of the remote tables?

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading something wrong, but I don't think the syntax of the inserts into `table2` and `table3` are correct. There seems to be something missing after the `@MC_Link` in both statements - perhaps there should be a `WHERE`. Best of luck.